# Best way to edit Linux server configuration files on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, configuration, textmate

I'm used to editing my remote Ubuntu server through SSH and Nano. I've tried using Vim and Emacs but since I don't manage the server frequently enough I never quite get the hang of it and end up forgetting the commands.

I use TextMate daily for programming and was wondering if there's any counter-recommendation against mounting the server's /etc/ folder locally using http://www.macfusionapp.org/ and creating a TextMate project containing /etc/ and editing all configuration files right within?

root would have to be used through SSH to allow editing of the /etc/ files so that makes me a little nervous. Is this a bad approach?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) to remotely edit files. You can set up SFTP connections in Cyberduck, so you can connect to any remote machine to which you have SSH access. Cyberduck lets you use TextMate as an external editor, so you can set up the connection and start editing, and Cyberduck will automatically upload your changes.

(This is probably possible in other FTP clients like Transmission, too, but I personally use Cyberduck so I don't know much about other clients.)

There's nothing wrong with using MacFUSE, but I find the Cyberduck solution to be simpler.